# 'whoami' returns 'root' - how do I set myself up as user?

Tags: username

Just installed Ubuntu on Windows 10, I am a total beginner and new to this and I did see the prompt to provide my username, but by the time I found out what my username was (which had to match Windows apparently), that prompt was gone and never came back. pwd returns '/root', and whoami returns 'root'. Help -  I don't even know how to google these things! :)

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing the answer:

1. Firstly, check if you have a user created for yourself,
   For that, check

   `passwd username`

   If the command says user doesn't exist. You would have to create a new user.
2. To create a new user

   `adduser username`
3. Once you have the user created and password setup, to change to a different user, type `su` followed by a space and your username. Type the password when prompted.
4. Also check if you have a shell assigned to your username. Refer this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217912/login-as-non-root-user-in-terminal)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exaclt my question. I don't even HAVE a username or if I do I don't know what it is.

Comment: Hi Anna, try out instructions mentioned here to create a new user:

Comment: Ok so i tried that with firstnamelastname, seemed to work but says there is no password entry and it prompts me for a new password, but when I type the cursor doesn't react/move...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-add.html.en

Comment: The entered password is invisible on the prompt. Type your password and press enter.

Comment: Great! That seemed to work. But I still don't have a directory.. I am still in root and I am going through the tutorial which suggests that something like mark@linux-desptop: ~$ appears in the prompt, but for me it is root@DESKTOP-CDXXXXX:/# (XX being my pc name)

Comment: do su - username

Comment: although I got the confimration that password updated successfully, when i do su - username, I get 'No passwd entry for user 'myusername' :(

Comment: Try out the steps here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/how-to-change-password-on-ubuntu/

Comment: That's what I did and the thing is that it seems I am not 'logged in' or the command line  ramesh@ramesh-desktop:~$ passwd (in that example) is still the root@DESKTOP one for me. In Windows 10 the GUI steps don't work either... sorry about this!

Comment: Okay, so, update your question with all the screenshots for the screens so that I can get a sense of what's happening. I'll help you out, don't worry!

Comment: just did. thank you again!

Comment: sudo passwd annamartinez

Comment: While you did passwd, you were actually changing the root password. Unless you specifically mentioned which user, the logged in user password gets updated.

Comment: "passwd: user 'annamartinez' does not exist" .. whch is what I suspected!

Comment: Okay. The user wasn't created. You can now create one. Do adduser annamartinez, set the password, for user information prompt fill the details or leave it blank. Then do: usermod -aG sudo annamartinez. Then login as you, su - annamartinez

Comment: :) hooray! Thank you that worked! Btw, since I changed the root password - is that a problem? And what was the default one?

Comment: and when closing the terminal and reopening? is there a way to always by default open it as myself in my own directory?

Comment: You might have to go to the settings and re-login as you. As long as you remember the password you set for the previous passwd commands you should be all set.

Comment: Also check this similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217912/login-as-non-root-user-in-terminal, check if you have a shell assigned for your username.

Comment: thank you.. again! will have a read. I have actually been looking for settings, but cannot find them. All i can change are graphics and stuff like that under properties....